# Parsing MediaWiki text in Java reliably (according to stated criteria)

Tags: java, mediawiki

I'm trying to find an API so that I can avoid building something (in Java) that can convert MediaWiki syntax to HTML myself. This seems to be a sufficiently general problem that someone else should have solved it, but thus far I've been digging around on the internet with no luck.

My first pick was Mylyn Wikitext, which seems to work somewhat, but I'm using Maven, and the Maven repository version is still 0.94, and it seems to only support a subset of the full Mediawiki syntax -- in particular, it is missing the ability to replace {{quote|sample quote text}} with blockquotes.

I also tried Bliki v3.0.19, and it also seems to be missing blockquotes.

Based on a quick survey, many of the other available options look like they are either no longer maintained, still in alpha (e.g. Sweble), or like they are projects with a single contributor, so they may be less likely to be bug-free.

So, does anyone know of a Java library for parsing MediaWiki and generating HTML that meets the following criteria? (My intent is to be specific and concrete about what I'm looking for, so it's more a binary choice than a matter of opinion.)

1. Still maintained -- to be more specific, it's been updated within the last two years
2. Actually supports Mediawiki {{quote}} syntax in addition to more standard markup like bold/italics/lists/links
3. More than one contributor to source code and at least hundreds of users (as evidence that most bugs and performance issues are likely to have been worked out)
4. Latest versions are available from the central Maven repository.

Extra credit would go to an API where the parsing language is easily extensible, and where elements of the language can also be removed.

Thanks!

Comment: `{{quote}}` is not part of MediaWiki syntax, but the name of a template on several Wikipedia's. To do transclusion is a complex task, as the result might look different depending on from where the template is called (e.g. by the use of magic words, such as `{{PAGENAME}}`). The best way to be sure to get it right is probably to use the MediaWiki API. That has built in support for converting markup to html, taking context (current page) into consideration.

Comment: Oh, I had no idea {{quote}} wasn't part of the MediaWiki syntax--that's super helpful to know. In that case, a MediaWiki API implementation that can easily be extended (so that I could add a simplified verison of the {{quote|text}} functionality that simply places the text within <blockquote> tags would be sufficient. When you suggest using the MediaWiki API, running something in PHP is not an option for me, so that still leaves the question of which Java implementation to use.

Comment: You don't need to use PHP, MediaWiki has an API that you can either use directly, or wrap in some Java lib.: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers lists such attempts, but none can fulfill your requirements, i.e. being able to parse site-specific markup like an individual [template](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Templates).

The [parsing API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) used via [Java clients](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Client_code#Java) is likely to be your best chance. If for some reason you cannot rely on HTTP requests, please clarify your use case in the question.

Comment: As stated in this answer, it turned out that there was no solution that met my possibly unrealistic criteria. I ended up compromising and going with MarkdownJ, because in while it uses Markdown syntax instead of MediaWiki syntax and has not been updated in over a year, it is simpler than some of the other options and thus far it has turned out to be reliable.